# Batch scripting - pulling a random variable that is never identical from command to a line in batch script

Tags: batch-file, encryption, command-line

I am stuck on a certain area of batch scripting that involves getting a password that displays in command prompt into a batch script to run. This password is never identical so I believe I need to set a variable but I am unaware on how to do so.

For example {08BB9799-7942-4B17-8270-sdajhauh} would be the numerical password and I need to write it to this line.

manage-bde -keypackage c: -id {password that needs to be entered} -path b:

Any help would be appreciated,
Cheers.

Comment: `set var=value`. See the documentation for [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) for more details. Later you can reference it with `%var%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you're setting a variable,

```
set/ p password=Enter password: 
manage-bde -keypackage c: -id %password% -path b:
```

Comment: I won't be setting a variable exactly like above. I am creating a variable but then I'm trying to set it to a certain index within command prompt.